# apt stopped, dpkg.log shows several 'status half-configured'

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am running Budgie 20_04.

Recently my notebook twice shut down with 'thermal_zone0: acpitz: critical temperature reached' while I was updating software via the apt gui. I assume the (post) installation scripts have already been running while this emergengy shutdown occured. Possibly this is the reason that I see some 'status half-configured' in dpkg.log.
Now I plan to avoid the apt gui, and I try to clear and repair using the apt-get command instead.

1. how can I determine any package that is not in a good shape in terms of dkpk ?
2. how best to fix?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc' ` shows you packages that are not complete installed or deinstalled.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, this results in: 
 Gewünscht=Unbekannt/Installieren/R=Entfernen/P=Vollständig Löschen/Halten
| Status=Nicht/Installiert/Config/U=Entpackt/halb konFiguriert/
         Halb installiert/Trigger erWartet/Trigger anhängig
|/ Fehler?=(kein)/R=Neuinstallation notwendig (Status, Fehler: GROSS=schlecht) .  
 So obviously everything is correct.